# how to use Snap-to-Place Technologies provided by foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

I tried to fill foursquare form twice but I did not answer nothing from him. Please let me how to use foursquare's API for Snap-to-Place Technology.

I am developing an iOS application in which I want to convert latitude and longitude in place name. So I found this technology very helpful. So let me know how to use this api.

Comment: Could you give an example of the request you are sending to be more precise?

Comment: I tried to fill form at this url https://places.foursquare.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to contact foursquare in order to use their API. You can just run an HTTP query giving your lattitude and longitude as parameters, as described in [this piece of documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search).

From what I understand, the "Snap-to-place" functionnality is just a fancy name for their normal API capability.

You should create an "app" in foursquare beforehand, though; just follow the instructions in [the getting started section](https://developer.foursquare.com/start), then replace `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` in your calls by thoses generated for your app in the foursquare web console, and give in your coordinates as parameters. More information about what you can do with the API is provided in [the detailed documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/).

You should then run something like:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=30.713100,76.709038&radius=200&limit=1&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20151029
```

You should then adjust the radius, and verify that the result that you are expecting is registered in foursquare's database if it does not match. If you have a specific type of location you want to target, you could also use `query=YOUR_TYPE_OF_PLACE` and `intent=match`

Comment: I used this latitude and longitude : 30.713100,76.709038 in foursquare's API but it returned me KFC as place name. But this is not where i am

Comment: I edited my answer to add a query example. I personally get offices named "Serco".

Comment: (it's in Mohali, India, and matches the place I'm getting on Google Maps.)